# Java regex pattern to match only the last ocurrence of string

Tags: java, html, regex

In a html doc, I need to replace the full path to files with just the file names.
The documents are very large so I think I can use regex to obtain a practical solution. I've already read similar questions and tried the solutions but that just did'nt work.

Example. Given this html input.

```
<img src="app/javax.faces.resource/color_pan.png?ln=img/partidos" style="width:100%; height:30px;" class="centerImg"/>
<img src="/app/javax.faces.resource/pan.png?ln=img/partidos" class="centerImg"/>
```

I need the folowing output:

```
<img src="color_pan.png" style="width:100%; height:30px"; class="centerImg"/>
<img src="pan.png" class="centerImg"/>
```

I'm trying these patterns:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("src=\"(?=.*src).*/color_pan.png[^\"]*\"");
Patter p1 = Pattern.compile("src=\"(?!.*src).*/pan.png[^\"]*\"");
```

The first one works fine for the 1st image and the second one is the solution for the 2nd (both are on the same html doc).
I need a general pattern that works for every image. So the problem is to find only the first "src" element that appears left to the file name. In other words, the "src" must be the last one that appears before the file name.
That way, I could replace the strings correctly.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I would first trim everything after the `?` from your string... then get the trim everything before the last `/` from the remaining string (in other words, I would not use regex in this case :) )

Answer (score 0):

This regex seems to do the work

**Solution 1 <=** 2 matches in 1509 steps

```
(^<img src=")(?:.*?)([\w.]+)(?=\?)[^"]*"(.*$)
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/zL0wS2/1)

*Towards an efficient solution*

**Solution 2 <=** 2 matches in 593 steps

```
(^<img src=").*(?<=\/|")([\w.]+)(?=\?)[^"]*"(.*$)
```

*Java Code*

```
String pattern = "(^<img src=\")(?:.*?)([\\w.]+)(?=\\?)[^\"]*\"(.*$)";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

while (true) {
     String line = x.nextLine();
     Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
     if (m.find()) {
         System.out.println(m.group(1) + m.group(2) + m.group(3));
     } else {
         System.out.println("Not Found");
     }
}
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/M5PXiG)**